# wrong container: package javafx.util does not exist

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, cirrus-ci

i'm implementing a JavaFX-Application and use [Cirrus-CI](https://cirrus-ci.org/) for continuous Integragtion for Github.

this is my build-configuration `.cirrus.yml`:

```
container:
  image: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8

build_task:
  build_script: mvn clean compile test sonar:sonar
```

During build it has problems in finding the JavaFX lib from within the installed JDK(these error log lines are just examples, there are many many more):

```
[ERROR] /tmp/cirrus-ci-build/src/main/java/com/github/martinfrank/catansettler/gui/ControllerFactory.java:[4,19] package javafx.util does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/cirrus-ci-build/src/main/java/com/github/martinfrank/catansettler/gui/alert/GameSetupAlertController.java:[6,28] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
```

### Note:

of course, with my local DevEnvirnment it's working...

### Question:

what's the proper setup (Cirrus Build Definition) which includes a JDK with JavaFx?
(or am i doing something complety wrong here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `openjfx`. You can do it like this:

```
container:
  image: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8

build_task:
  install_script:
    - apt-get update 
    - apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y openjfx
  build_script: mvn clean compile test sonar:sonar
```

You can also consider using [Dockerfile as a CI environment](https://cirrus-ci.org/guide/docker-builder/#dockerfile-as-a-ci-environment) feature and create a Dockerfile like this (with `.ci/Dockerfile` relative path in your repository):

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y openjfx \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists
```

And you is in your `.cirrus.yml`:

```
build_task:
  container:
    dockerfile: .ci/Dockerfile
  build_script: mvn clean compile test sonar:sonar
```

This will strip of 30-40 seconds which takes to execute the `install` script.

Comment: Thank you very much. Right now I'm already in the weekend. I'll try it out on Monday and accept it if it's working (but I'm sure it will work)

Comment: Thanks again for pointing out the details concerning a custom docket container. That seems a very good idea. As said I'll try it out on Monday - thank you very very much

Comment: installing the packages does not solve the problem, i'll look out for the solution with creating a custom docker file

Comment: thanks @fkorotkov - i had some other issues what prevented me from your solution, but that's what it does it now!!!

Comment: Great! Could you please then answer your own question for future researchers? 